# Can I create all CRUD Operations in a Surface Controller in Umbraco?

Tags: crud, umbraco, surface-controller, umbraco-10

So I was wondering if it is possible to use a Surface Controller for all crud operations (Umbraco V10). I know that I can create a Post method, but is it possible to add a Delete or Patch method?

I tried to add a method like this:

```
public class DeleteController : SurfaceController {
    [HttpDelete]
    public IActionResult Delete()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

but I only receive an 405 error telling me that the method is not allowed. If I change the `[HttpDelet]` to `[HttpPost]` the method works, but I think that is semantically not correct if i delete content in a POST method.

And am I correct in saying that it is not common to have multiple methods in one Surface Controller? So I would have to create a Controller for each method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use your Surface Controller for different CRUD operations. Below is a sample code from [the Umbraco CMS document](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/surface-controllers).

Please take a look at this guide for [more details.](https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-9-tutorials/getting-started-with-umbraco-9/ultimate-umbraco-v9-controller-guide/)

[Here is another old but useful approach.](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/79088-crud-operation-in-umbraco-using-surface-controller)

PS: The attribute issue that you see could be a bug.You can check the existing Umbraco CMS issues [here.](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/issues)

```
    namespace RoutingDocs.Controllers;
    ​
    public class MyController : SurfaceController
    {
        public MyController(
            IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor,
            IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory,
            ServiceContext services,
            AppCaches appCaches,
            IProfilingLogger profilingLogger,
            IPublishedUrlProvider publishedUrlProvider)
            : base(umbracoContextAccessor, databaseFactory, services, appCaches, profilingLogger, publishedUrlProvider)
        {
        }
    ​
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateUmbracoFormRouteString]
        public IActionResult HandleSubmitMethod1()
        {
            return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateUmbracoFormRouteString]
        public IActionResult HandleSubmitMethod2()
        {
           return Content("Hello Postback");
        }
    }
```